# Unable to run docker image for golang in windows

Tags: bash, docker, go

I have created an image in windows 10 git bash. After so many turn around's I finally able to create an image in windows using docker.

But the problem is that when I try to run the container it shows me an error. I have tried everything. My DOCKERFILE is:

```
# Start from a Debian image with the latest version of Go installed
# and a workspace (GOPATH) configured at /go.
FROM golang:latest AS builder
# install golang dependency management tool
RUN go get -u github.com/golang/dep/cmd/dep
# RUN go get -u -v github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger

# RUN CHMOD 777 -R .

# COPY . $GOPATH/src/app
RUN mkdir $GOPATH/src/project
# RUN mkdir $GOPATH/src/app/swagger
# WORKDIR /go/src/app 
WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/project
# Add main file to /go/src/app

ADD . $GOPATH/src/project
ADD ./swagger/* $GOPATH/src/app/swagger/

# Copy Gopkg files to install dependencies
COPY ./Gopkg.toml /go/src/project
COPY ./Gopkg.lock /go/src/project
# COPY ./swagger/swagger.yaml /go/src/app

RUN dep ensure -update -v
RUN go install -v ./...

CMD ["project"]
```

The image is created. But I am unable to run a container from the image it always shows and error:

> C:/Program Files/Docker/Docker/Resources/bin/docker.exe: Error
>   response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
>   container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec:
>   \"C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/ba sh.exe\": stat C:/Program
>   Files/Git/usr/bin/bash.exe: no such file or directory": unknown.

If I tried to look into the image contents . It is asking to run the container first. How should one is able to view the files and check for an error.

Comment: I ran your dockerfile from Win10 cmd.exe and it works. I only commented out the run of `dep ensure update -v` since I don't have the toml files. I used the follwing commands `docker build -t so-container .` and `docker run so-container`. The app I added to the container is a go webserver.

Comment: let me try from cmd. I was running from git bash.

Comment: Tried in git bash, works as well. I suppose it is either the binary you are running or something with the `dep`-tool

Comment: @thst It is working with powershell but not with git bash. But still I can manage with powershell for now the error is with some path that docker daemon is unable to find the binary executable file in the given path